# Book about time series analysis in Stata

Tags: time-series, references, stata

Does somebody know a good book which outlines the time series analysis in Stata, that is, the various commands explained. I am aware of the Stata manuals; however, they are not that user friendly for me. I am searching for a book similar to "Microeconometrics using Stata" by Cameron and Trivedi which is related to time series analysis.

Comment: http://www.stata.com/bookstore/books-on-stata/ includes all reputable books with major Stata content. The book by Becketti focuses on time series. I doubt that there is any book that covers all Stata time series analysis in extremely friendly form. Several techniques are necessarily demanding technically and don't lend themselves to low-level introductions.

Comment: I think Stata manuals are very well written.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [book review](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=gn0060) of Sean Becketti's *[Introduction to Time Series Using Stata](http://www.stata.com/bookstore/introduction-to-time-series-using-stata/)* that you may find useful. I think this is as close to C&T for TS as you're going to get.